# Does the Annihilator for a differential equation have to be injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have not yet taken a class in linear algebra, but I am currently taking a class on differential equations that uses annihilators. I was wondering if it was a requirement for an annihilator to be injective. I am thinking that if it wasn't injective, the annihilator wouldn't be a linear transformation, but I do not know how that disqualifies it as a method to solve an ODE.

Comment: Tell me how do you would to work that

Comment: If you are asking for an example of an Annihilator L that would bring L(f) to 0, I cannot think of an example, but that may be because of my lack of experience in linear algebra. Is the reason why an Annihilator has to be injective, because there are no Annihilators that are not injective?

Comment: If an annihilator is an operator that maps a subspace to zero, then it is obviously not injective, it maps any affine subspace parallel to the original one to the same image.